# User resizable div - is it possible to drag&drop resize divs?

Tags: html, textarea

I have the following code:

```css
#test {
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px;
    padding:5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

Does any function exist which achieves this with my `<div>`? The user can edit the height and `width` similar to a textarea but as a `<div>`

Comment: [jQuery UI Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/).

Answer (score 1):

Use moar **jQuery** UI Resizable plugin:
Include jQuery `(min.js, UI.js, UI.css)` in your website and use the `.resizable()` function.

The jQuery UI Resizable plugin makes selected elements resizable (meaning they have draggable resize handles). You can specify one or more handles as well as min and max width and height.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#test").resizable();
});
```

```css
#test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js></script><link href=//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css rel=stylesheet><script src=https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js></script>

<div id="test">
  Some Text
</div>
```